# Creating a concatenated string of ints Python

Tags: python, loops, concatenation

I am iterating through some range of numbers and creating a string of concatenated numbers that fit my criteria. However, I'm not getting the output that I want. I'm new to python, so I might be missing something here. Here is my code:

```
my_lst = []
for x in range(10):
  my_lst.append(str(x))
counter = 0
weird_num = 0
for y in range(10):
  if my_lst[y] <  5:
    weird_num = weird_num + my_lst[y]
  counter = counter + 1

print weird_num, counter
```

The output is `0 10` and I want the output to be `012345 10`. The idea is that I am trying to build this string of ints so I might be having issues with casting but I'm not sure. Also, any tips to improve my python code would be appreciated since I'm new! Thanks

Comment: You're comparing a string to an integer - how do you expect that to work?

Comment: Wow, so many responses, it'll take me a while to sort through all these. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings with an integer:

```
if my_lst[y] < 5:
```

In Python 2, strings *always* sort after numbers:

```
>>> '1' < 5
False
>>> '9' < 5
False
```

As a result, `weird_num` remains just the initial value, the integer `0`. If your loop had worked, you would have had an error telling you you cannot concatenate integers and strings

Compare against a string instead, and start `weird_num` as an empty string, and if you want `5` to be included, test for lower *or equal*:

```
weird_num = ''
if my_lst[y] <= '5':
```

or, much simpler, just concatenate the first 6 values in your list; your list contains the digits from `'0'` through to `'9'` in sorted order:

```
weird_num = ''.join(my_lst[:6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `my_lst[y]` is a string so it cannot be compared to an `int`. Here's some code that will produce the output that you want. I've also included some things that will make your python code look better!

```
my_lst = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
weird_num = ""
for counter, y in enumerate(range(10), 1):
  if int(my_lst[y]) <=  5:
    weird_num = weird_num + my_lst[y]
print weird_num, counter
```

This will produce the output that you want.

Now, let me explain some of the parts I included. On line `1`, instead of creating an empty list, and then populating it with a for loop, I am using a list comprehension to populate the list the minute I make it. More info about list comprehensions can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Basically, it's sticking a a for loop onto one list inside a list that populates the list.

Next, I made `weird_num` an empty list. This is so that you can start concatenating your `my_lst` elements inside the for loop. If you were to initialize it with `weird_num = "0"`, you would have an extra zero on the left side of your output.

For the for loop, I used an `enumerate`, more info for which can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). It turns your for loop into an enumerate object, which means you can keep track of a variable like `counter` through the whole thing. `counter` will go from 0 -> 9, but I added the extra parameter of `1` so that it will go from 1 -> 10.

Finally, inside the for loop, I just had to cast `my_lst[y]` to `int` so that you can do the comparison logic.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for including ways that I can improve!

Answer (score 1):

`weird_num` should be a string. Replace `weird_num = 0` with `weird_num = ""`. Also, you are comparing numbers with strings, which won't produce the results you want.

Try this instead:

```
my_lst = []
for x in range(10):
  my_lst.append(x)
counter = 0
weird_num = ""
for y in range(10):
  if my_lst[y] <  5:
    weird_num = weird_num + str(my_lst[y])
  counter = counter + 1
print weird_num, counter
```

Other things:

You can replace `counter = counter + 1` with `counter += 1`.
You could (and should) replace the second `for` loop with this:

```
for y in my_lst:
  if y <  5:
    weird_num = weird_num + str(y)
  counter = counter + 1
```

This iterates directly over the list.

When joining strings it is better to use the function `str.join`. An example:

```
>>> lst = ["Hello", "world", "!"]
>>> "...".join(lst)
Hello...world...!
```

You could replace your entire code with something like this:

```
my_lst = list(range(10))
weird_num = "".join(str(i) for i in my_lst if i < 5)
counter = len(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? If you just want a string consisting of all integers up to (but not including) a certain value, you can do:

```
weird_num = "".join(str(x) for x in range(value))
```

---

In more detail, here's what your code is doing:

```
my_lst = []
for x in range(10):
    my_lst.append(str(x))
```

This creates a list of strings of the ten single-digit integers: `['0', '1', '2', ..., '9']`. In this list, each item is the string representation of its index, i.e. for every value `my_lst[x] == str(x)`. This isn't a terribly useful list, because you can just call `str(x)` if you need the string.

```
counter = 0
...
for y in range(10): 
    ...
    counter = counter + 1
```

Throughout this loop, `counter == y`. You only need one or the other; you don't actually use `counter` inside the loop. As you already know how many times you will loop, you could easily do `counter = 10` then `for y in range(counter)`, which means you don't need to increment `counter` inside the loop. Also, you can increment more elegantly in Python: `counter += 1`.

```
for y in range(10):
    if my_lst[y] < 5:
        ...
```

As others have pointed out, the problem here is you are comparing a string with an integer (you can fix this either with `int(my_lst[y]) < 5` or `my_lst[y] < str(5)`, but as I note above we already know that `my_lst[y] == str(y)`.

However, it is also worth highlighting that you don't need to do this check. You could simply stop looping earlier, as we already know the items in the list are just string representations of each integer:

```
for y in range(5):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that my_lst holds strings, so the "< 5" comparison is not valid (this comparison does not do what you think in this case).

You can cast the my_lst value back to "int" for the comparison:

```
my_lst = []
for x in range(10):
  my_lst.append(str(x))
counter = 0
weird_num = ''
for y in range(10):
  if int(my_lst[y]) <=  5:
    weird_num = weird_num + my_lst[y]
  counter = counter + 1

print weird_num, counter
```

A couple of other points:

1. since weird_num is intended as a string, you should define it as string `weird_num = ''`
2. since you want "5" included in the output, you need to all for "equal to" in your comparison: `<=  5:`